# timescaledb - out of shared memory when loading a 4GB file to a hypertable

Tags: postgresql, csv, timescaledb

:)
I have Gentoo Linux, with postgresql 11.4 and timescaledb-1.3.2.
I executed timescaledb-tune to tune my postgresql database configuration.

I created a table with like 30 fields, lets call it foo. 
I created another duplicated table, just created it as an hypertable, lets call it h_foo.

I have a 4gb csv file that I Try to load to the database with the `COPY ... FROM ...` command

when I try to load the data to a regular table, it takes less then a minute and that's it, done.

when I try to load it to the hypertable, after a while it complains that it's out of shared memory and it takes a long time till it reaches the error point.

I assumed that working with timescaledb out of the box (without knowing advanced configuration) would worth the effort but i'm not sure anymore.

I'll paste my postgresql configuration file below, please let me know if there is anything that I can modify who would help me out in loading that csv file.

thank you

```
shared_buffers = 8009MB                 # min 128kB
work_mem = 6835kB                               # min 64kB
maintenance_work_mem = 2047MB           # min 1MB
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix      # the default is the first option
effective_io_concurrency = 200          # 1-1000; 0 disables prefetching
max_worker_processes = 23               # (change requires restart)
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 6     # taken from max_parallel_workers
max_parallel_workers = 12               # maximum number of max_worker_processes that
wal_buffers = 16MB                      # min 32kB, -1 sets based on shared_buffers
max_wal_size = 8GB
min_wal_size = 4GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9      # checkpoint target duration, 0.0 - 1.0
random_page_cost = 1.1                  # same scale as above
effective_cache_size = 24029MB
default_statistics_target = 500 # range 1-10000
log_timezone = 'Israel'
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
timezone = 'Israel'
lc_messages = 'en_US.utf8'                      # locale for system error message
                                        # strings
lc_monetary = 'en_US.utf8'                      # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'en_US.utf8'                       # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'en_US.utf8'                          # locale for time formatting
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
shared_preload_libraries = 'timescaledb'
max_locks_per_transaction = 256        # min 10
plperl.on_init = 'use utf8; use re; package utf8; require "utf8_heavy.pl";'
timescaledb.max_background_workers = 8
timescaledb.last_tuned = '2019-07-14T16:06:04+03:00'
timescaledb.last_tuned_version = '0.6.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This obviously shouldn't happen...

Can you describe your CSV data in more depth?  What does your table schema and `create_hypertable` call look like, and what time range is your data?  By default we create a chunk per week of timestamps.  Have you changed that setting with `create_hypertable`, or does your data cover a huge time-range?

(For example, we saw one user who once accidentally set the DB to create a chunk per second, and then tried a COPY that attempted to create a million chunks.  The DB wasn't super happy...)

Comment: thank you for your answer. for now I just created a fake data to play with. the time range of the data is really long (maybe 10-20 years). I didn't change anything in create_hypertable function, just used it to create a hypertable and specified a specific time range column. the csv contains about 30 fields, mostly strings

Comment: So with 20 years, it's going to create 52*20 = 1040 chunks (tables) during that COPY command, and it's going to need to be able to take a lock per table.  Yet the config above has max_locks_per_transaction = 256.

(PostgreSQL unfortunately returns an OOM message if runs out of locks; wish it was something more clarifying.)

I recommend either bumping up max locks to something even like 8192 or 16384, or actually tuning the parameters a bit more.

Unless I know more about your workload, ~4GB over 1000 chunks is probably a bit smaller than recommended.

Comment: oops my bad :) the data is for 1500 years back! i'll create a new fake data that will go for several years back and that's it.

Comment: Yep, the DB was trying to create 78,000 chunks with that one COPY command.  Makes me feel better :)

Comment: ahah thanks a lot :)  I didn't notice that my huge amount of test data was till 1500 years back! fixed it to several years and it's lightning fast!